# how to store audio file in Sdcard captured using getUserMedia in fire fox os

Tags: javascript, storage, audio-recording, firefox-os

i am creating one app where when i will press save button it will store given blob audion data in to SDcard in firefox os here i am  presenting code for it.

```
   var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
           audio.src = audioURL;
           audio.type="video/ogg";

           deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
             evtTgt = e.target;
             evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
           }

           saveButton.onclick = function(e) {
             evtTgt = e.target;
             var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage("sdcard");
            var file   = new Blob([audioURL], {type: "video/ogg"});

            var request = sdcard.addNamed(file, "my-file.ogg");

                request.onsuccess = function () {
                var name = this.result;
                console.log('File "' + name + '" successfully wrote on the sdcard storage area');

}
```

here i have written the code but it is not working.so plz any one can help??

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get the data from the `MediaRecorder` event object that is passed to the handler of the `"dataavailable"` event like in the example outlined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable

In this case `e.data` is already a Blob and you can simply pass it to the `addNamed` function as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceStorage/addNamed

```
var audioData = e.data,
    audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
audio.src = audioURL;
audio.type ="video/ogg";

deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
    evtTgt = e.target;
    evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
}

saveButton.onclick = function(e) {
    evtTgt = e.target;
    var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage("sdcard");
    var request = sdcard.addNamed(audioData, "my-file.ogg");

    request.onsuccess = function () {
        var name = this.result;
        console.log('File "' + name + '" successfully wrote on the sdcard storage area');
    }
}
```

However, you should double-check your code since it seems to have unmatching brackets.

Comment: now i want toget the result of browsed data from sdcard music folder.here is sample code.